# Method Program not displaying expected result

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class method
{
    static int ABC (int A, int B, int C)
    {
        if (A == B)
        {
            C = A;
            return C;
        }
        else
        {
            C = B;
            return C;
        } 

    }


    public static void main (String str[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#");

        int X = 5;
        int Y = -3; 
        int Z = 0;

        ABC (X, Y, Z);

    }
}
```

Above is my method code, however I don't understand why nothing is displayed when the program is run. If anyone knows why that would help? Thank you.

Comment: What about printing the result? `System.out.println();`

Comment: ABC(X,Y,Z); -> System.out.println(ABC(X,Y,Z));

Comment: Calculating a result is not enough, if you want to display something you have to print it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the result returned by your method `ABC` like:

```
System.out.println(ABC (X, Y, Z));
```

Couple of things:

1. Are you expecting the values of X/Y/Z to be read from keyboard? Or you should get rid of BufferedReader.
2. You should follow naming convention while defining methods or variables. Your method name ABC is wrong here. *Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.* (from [oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)) You can learn more about naming coneventions in java on the [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).
3. You should avoid unnecessary assignment and can do it like:

   ```
   if (A == B) {            
       return A;
   }
   else {            
       return B;
   }
   ```

Comment: what about just a `return B` ? :)

Comment: Yes you are right, i intentionally avoided that. Just wanted to simplify the `if/else` part so he understands how `if/else` works